# list Index Error (even though it exists)?

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, xml-parsing

I'm running a for loop to grab content out of some XML and it works fine, until I reach around the 29th iteration. At that point it gives me this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
  return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)   
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
  return method(*args, **kwargs)   
File "J:\Art & Graphic Design\Graphic Design\Websites\lawvoter-dev\cron_congressman.py", line 64, in get
  birthday      = re.findall("<birthday>(.*)</birthday>",element)[0] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is:

```
for element in members:
            title         = re.findall("<title>(.*)</title>",element)[0]
            role          = re.findall("<role_type_label>(.*)</role_type_label>",element)[0]
            name_sortable = re.findall("<name_sortable>(.*)</name_sortable>",element)[0]
            firstname     = re.findall("<firstname>(.*)</firstname>",element)[0]
            lastname      = re.findall("<lastname>(.*)</lastname>",element)[0]
            gender        = re.findall("<gender_label>(.*)</gender_label>",element)[0]
            birthday      = re.findall("<birthday>(.*)</birthday>",element)[0]
            party         = re.findall("<party>(.*)</party>",element)[0]
            state         = re.findall("<state>(.*)</state>",element)[0]
            description   = re.findall("<description>(.*)</description>",element)[0]
            start_date    = re.findall("<startdate>(.*)</startdate>",element)[0]
            end_date      = re.findall("<enddate>(.*)</enddate>",element)[0]
            website       = re.findall("<website>(.*)</website>",element)[0]
            bioguideid    = re.findall("<bioguideid>(.*)</bioguideid>",element)[0]
            osid          = re.findall("<osid>(.*)</osid>",element)[0]
            pvsid         = re.findall("<pvsid>(.*)</pvsid>",element)[0]
            twitterid     = re.findall("<twitterid>(.*)</twitterid>",element)[0]
            youtubeid     = re.findall("<youtubeid>(.*)</youtubeid>",element)[0]

            member = Congressman(title=title, role=role, name_sortable=name_sortable, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, gender=gender, birthday=birthday, party=party, state=state,
                                 description=description, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, website=website, bioguideid=bioguideid, osid=osid, pvsid=pvsid, twitterid=twitterid, youtubeid=youtubeid)
            member.put()
```

I really don't get why this error is popping up? It always works fine for the first 29 iterations? The each element in the datamodel is also set to "default=None" just in case. However, when I look at the XML itself, and go to the exact line where the error happens, the value is actually there. Anyone know why it would give an error even though the value exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like

```
birthday      = re.findall("<birthday>(.*)</birthday>",element)[0]
```

returns an empty list and you are trying to extract the first element which is not in the list and it throws the

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

like here:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

EDIT:

```
import re, logging

def findelement(item, element):
    i = re.findall(item, element)
    if not i:
        logging.info('no item found for %s with element %s' %(item, element))
        return ''
    return i[0]


for element in members:
    title = findelement("<title>(.*)</title>", element)
    ...
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but when I print out that line that iteration prints a value in the list. Similar to:

`>> a=['1984-10-20']
>>> a[0]
IndexError??`

Comment: similar or exactly? you are iterating members so ther might be that element in that specific iteration does return an empty list. try to log the results.

Comment: When I was looking at the XML it shows up, but I threw a print in after the "birthday" and after the 29th iteration I get a "Status: 500" error.

Comment: that 500 error is because of the `IndexError`. that iteration returns an empty list. you need to figure out how to deal with this. make a function with a `try/except` clause to deal with the error.

Comment: check my edit and try to use this helper function which logs the result if the returned list is empty so you can debug it.

Comment: Ok, so I just did a basic `try/except` to set the birthday equal to None if there's an IndexError. The entire for loop ran and after viewing the results in the datastore the 30th member was the only one with an empty field. I'm not really sure the best way to handle errors (never really dealt to much with try/except), but I am curious as to why the error is coming. Other fields that are actually non-existent for some members still go through and get set to None due to the `db.StringProperty(default=None)`.

EDIT: Ignore this, I posted it after your's and your edit. I'll look into it now.

Comment: no that does not make sense. what is failing is not GAE related. the issue you are having is only based on the IndexError by accessing the non existing element in the list at index 0. how you deal with values that are not set depends on how your app is designed

Comment: Okay, so after implementing your edit into the except, the log shows birthday as `<birthday type="null"/>`. Interesting, because if I go to the api url itself in the browser it shows it as existing.

Comment: with my edit you dont need any `try/except` the `findelement` function returns automatically an empty string if the list is empty.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. I'm sorry, I probably just need some sleep (been up all night working on this parsing and some other things). It just clicked with me. Thanks for all the help, would have been lost for awhile. :)